# PowerPC extsb in C

Tags: c++, assembly, powerpc

I'm trying to convert a PowerPC asm snippet to c++. This is what i've done so far:

```
PPC:
lis       r11, ((dword_83EEF800+0x10000)@h)
lis       r10, 0x20 # 0x207E90
addi      r11, r11, -0x800 # dword_83EEF800
ori       r10, r10, 0x7E90 # 0x207E90
lis       r9, 4 # 0x46E80
ori       r9, r9, 0x6E80 # 0x46E80
lwzx      r11, r11, r10
subf      r11, r11, r28
divw      r11, r11, r9
extsb     r3, r11 // Problem

C++:
DWORD r11 = 0x83EEF800 + 0x10000;
r11 += -0x800;
DWORD r10 = 0x207E90;
DWORD r9 = 0x46E80;
r11 = *(DWORD*)(r11 + r10);
r11 -= r28;
r11 /= r9;
```

Now my question, how exactly would i code "extsb" in c++? The documentation says it takes the least significant byte of in this case r11 and stores it into the low ordered 8 bits of r3. Then it places Bit 56 (in this case 24, since its a 32 bit register) into the remaining bits of r3. To get the least significant bytes of r11 i would do this:

```
r11 & 0xFF
```

But i'm not sure how to get bit 24 and use it to fill up the remaining bits of r3. I can only use native c++! If anybody knows how i can turn this ppc operation into c++ please let me know (please also let me know if there are any major mistakes in the converted ppc code i posted). Thanks in advance!

Reference: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.alangref/idalangref_extsb_instruction.htm

Comment: Can't you just use inline asm?

Comment: @user0042 like `DWORD r3; __asm { extsb r3, r11 }`? i could do that, but i want to understand how it would work in c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of the documentation entry for [`extsb`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.alangref/idalangref_extsb_instruction.htm) says the mnemonic is short for **Extend Sign Byte**.  i.e. perform [2's complement sign-extension.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension)

It looks like PowerPC docs number bits from the left, so the high bit is bit 0, and the low bit is bit 31.  The sign bit of the low 8 bits is thus bit 24, and this instruction is just performing sign-extension.

```
#include <stdint.h>
int32_t sign_extend_8(int src) {
  return (int32_t) (int8_t) src;
}
```

compiles to ([gcc4.8 for PowerPC, `-O3 -std=c++03`](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0Aint32_t+extsb(int+src)+%7B%0A++return+(int32_t)+(int8_t)+src%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//+requires+2!'s+complement+arithmetic+right+shifts%0Aint32_t+extsb_manual(uint32_t+src)+%7B%0A++src+%3C%3C%3D+24%3B%0A++return+((int32_t)src)+%3E%3E+24%3B++//+signed+right+shift.%0A%7D%0A%0A//+when+I+thought+the+low+8+bits+were+0-7%0Auint32_t+extsb_wrong(uint32_t+src)+%7B%0A++++int32_t+signbits+%3D+src+%3C%3C+(31-24)%3B++//+move+bit+24+to+the+top+(bit+31)%0A++++signbits+%3E%3E%3D+31%3B++++++++++++//+broadcast+the+sign+bit%0A%0A++++return+((uint32_t)signbits+%26+~0xFFU)+%7C+(src+%26+0xFFU)%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:38.33048345145499,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:ppcg48,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B03+-O3+-mregnames',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'PowerPC+gcc+4.8+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),k:31.442904894297897,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang500,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B03+-Wall+-O3+-march%3Dskylake',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+5.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)',t:'0')),header:(),k:30.22661165424713,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4), because Godbolt doesn't have a newer PPC gcc installed):

```
    extsb %r3,%r3
    blr
```

So does this, so we know they're both right:

```
// requires 2's complement arithmetic right shifts
int32_t extsb_manual(uint32_t src) {
  src <<= 24;
  return ((int32_t)src) >> 24;  // signed right shift.
}
```

ISO C++ says it's implementation-dependent what happens when you shift a negative number, but most implementations (and some dialects, for example GNU C++) guarantee 2's complement sign-extension for right shifts.  I.e. shift in copies of the high bit.

This lets you broadcast a bit with an arithmetic right shift.  e.g. `foo >> 31` produces either 0 or -1 (in a 2's complement system).

> i'm sorry, but im can't use c++11 :

[`#include <cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint) or `stdint.h` doesn't require C++11.  It's existed since at least C++03, if not earlier.  (Godbolt's PPC gcc4.8 appears to be partly broken, `#include <cstdint>` errors out, probably because it's from a newer gcc.  That's why I used the C `<stdint.h>` header even in C++.)

---

At first I was assuming "the low 8 bits" were 0-7, like on all other architectures I've ever seen, and that bit 24 was part of the high byte.  That would make for a very strange instruction, but here's how you could implement it (again using arithmetic right shift):

```
// requires 2's complement arithmetic right shifts
uint32_t extsb_wrong(uint32_t src) {
    int32_t signbits = src << (31-24);  // move bit 24 to the top (bit 31)
    signbits >>= 31;            // broadcast the sign bit

    // replace the low 8 of the 0 / -1 with the low 8 of the src    
    return ((uint32_t)signbits & ~0xFFU) | (src & 0xFFU);
}
```

This of course doesn't compile to `extsb`.  It's a bunch of actual shifting and AND / ORing.

Comment: Thanks alot, it's working now! :) You seem to know your stuff, keep up the good work!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest C equivalent is a cast through `int8_t`:

```
r3 = (int32_t) (int8_t) r11;
```

Comment: Oh, so the OP described `extsb` wrong?  They said that it broadcasts bit 24 of the original, not the sign-bit of the low 8.  I thought that the mnemonic sounds like it should be just sign-extension, but it's PowerPC so it could be anything...

Comment: i'm sorry, but im can't use c++11 :/

Comment: @PeterCordes i'm sorry i just paraphrased it, here's what i used as reference: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.alangref/idalangref_extsb_instruction.htm

Comment: @SupaDupa: Oh, PowerPC docs number bits from the left, so the low bit is bit 31!  You just said "the low 8 bits", and in all other architectures I've ever seen, that means bits 0-7.

Comment: yes, the low bit is bit 31, but they're talking about the least significant byte, i i thought that were 8 or 4 bits on the right side, so lets take `0x207E90 : 0000 0000 0010 0000 0111 1110 1001 0000`
here 0000 is the least significant byte, from what i understand.

Comment: @SupaDupa: `0000` is 4 bits.  That's the low nibble.  Also, this answer is valid C99 / C11, as well as valid C++11.  What makes you think this requires C++11?  Is it the types from `#include <stdint.h>`?  That's a C header.  (C++ also has `<cstdint>`.)

Comment: Or you can use the classic C names for the appropriate types — `char` and `long` should work on most 32-bit systems.